# Container with 'overflow-y: auto' adds extra horizontal and vertical scrolling bar

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML and CSS files containing the following code:

```
<div class="app">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="main">
       <div class="container_1">
           <h1>Item</h1>
           <h1>Item</h1>
           <h1>Item</h1>
                ..
       </div>
       <div class="container_2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.app{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 235, 147);
}

.main{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container_1{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 147, 147);
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.container_2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(147, 147, 255);
}
```

Which looks like this:
[page with header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cjBQ.png)

When removing the `div` element which contains the `header` class, the extra scrolling bars are gone (which is what i want):
[page without header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9LfD.png)

How can I get rid of the extra horizontal and vertical scrolling bars (not including the vertical one inside the `div` with the `container_1` class) without removing the `div` containing the `header` class?

Comment: The outer scrollbars are caused by the 100vw and 100vh on your `body` elem (when you add the scrollbar to container1, the vh units do not take the scrollbar width into account (use 100% instead))

I suspect you'll still have some unexpected behavior after resolving this, but it should be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:grid` is a better layout choice than flexbox for this:

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.app{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.header{
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 235, 147);
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

.main {
    display:contents;
}

.container_1{
    background-color: rgb(255, 147, 147);
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.container_2{
    background-color: rgb(147, 147, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="main">
       <div class="container_1">
           <h1>Item</h1>
           <h1>Item</h1>
           <h1>Item</h1>
           <h1>Item</h1>
           <h1>Item</h1>
           ...
       </div>
       <div class="container_2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate this on a Mac, but for me, it is working fine.
However, I would say, experiment using `overflow: hidden` on your elements.

You could try adding `overflow: hidden` to your `body` element and see how that goes.
Also, don't forget we also have `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` which are both useful.

[image: This html on mac]